# Rails's localhost : "is missing a template for request formats"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Ruby Rails newbie and I am trying to make a Rails page by this Youtube guide

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPy0GQJLZUM`

When I followed the page, I had this problem. When I tried to open the local host : localhost:3000, it gave me this notification

`PostsController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html`

In `\app\views\posts` I have the `index.html.erb` file like this

`<h1>Index</h1>`

And in `\app\controllers\posts_controller.rb` I have the `posts_controller.rb` file like this

`class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end`

In `\config\routes.rb` I have the `routes.rb` file like this 
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'posts#index' 
end`

I am a newbie, and very confuse with this problem. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I appreciate you say you have one, but that error message means there is no file located in `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` - look out for spelling errors and capital letters

Comment: As you can see in the video, they wrote in the `index.html.erb` file like this `<h1>Index</h1>`, so I followed them, am I wrong? Or may I need something more?

Comment: There is proprobaly a problem with filname as Mark said, can you show what's inside `app/viers/posts`?

Comment: Dear friends , thank you for your comments. It was just because my spelling error as Mr Mark said. Thank you very much.

Comment: It normally is, you're welcome :)